# Application deployment. Component Id. Application dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

I an have application which I want to deploy. I created a setup project, added content, primary output and resources to Application Folder.

There are several third party applications on which my application depends and I need to check whether they are installed. When the applications are installed, no specific registry entries are present.

I got their MSI packages. I know I should specify an MSI GUID (Component Id) in WI launch condition. When I load both these packages (mentioned above) into **orca** utility I get the following (odd) result:

[image]

How do I know which is my component? Why do component names have a strange representation?
Is there an alternate way of checking if another application exists when installing my package?

Answer (score 0):

Launch conditions stop the installation if their are not met. To install third party packages you can add them as prerequisites.

Visual Studio setup projects do not support custom prerequisite creation. However, it can be done by manually generating the required manifests.
You can find the manifests structure here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229223(VS.80).aspx

These manifests can be generated automatically with the [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg) tool.

After generating the package manifests, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages
```

After that you can select the prerequisites in your setup project property pages.

You can read more about prerequisites here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77z6b8tz(VS.80).aspx?ppud=4
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx

Regarding the detection criteria, I recommend using the [Product Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can find it in [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table.

Component names generated by Visual Studio are not user friendly. Also, you cannot use their names. At best you can use the ComponentId which is a GUID.

Components are not a reliable detection criteria and I do not recommend them.